# Reflect point in Group law on elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves

Let $E/\mathbb{Q}$ be an elliptic curve. When we add two points on an elliptic curve, we take the line joining them, take the third intersection point and then *reflect* the point and use that as the sum (at least in the generic case).

Why do we reflect the point? Is there a good reason? Is there a good low-level explanation or does it require some higher level algebraic geometry explanation? I don't think the group law itself suffers if we don't flip the point correct?

Comment: In the general case, if you want the point at infinity to be zero, then $0+P$ would be $-P$ if you didn't reflect the point.

Comment: Okay great that works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This rule can be applied when you assume that the zero element is the point of your elliptic curve at infinity:
More precisely, when the equation of the affine part has the form $y^2=(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)(x-\alpha_3)$.
It says that $P+Q+R=0$ if they lie on a line in the generic case.
This gives you a geometric way to find $-(P+Q)$.
For a generic finite point $P$ the line passing through $P$ and the point at infinity should intersect the curve at $-P$, which is the reflection point with respect to the $x$-axis.